# Detecting an image on the screen using Swift for a MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos, image, image-processing, swiftui

I would like to detect an image like this anywhere on my mac's display:

[image]

There will be many distinct repetitions on the screen at any one time, and I would like to find each of those found. I believe I will need some kind of Image object with my reference image, and then will need to either a) use a recognition library to search the screen for the reference, or perhaps scan pixel by pixel comparing against the reference (more manual and I think there must be an easier way).

When googling for how to do this in Swift, [I usually find information discussing AR, UIImageView](https://medium.com/@ios_guru/swiftui-and-image-recognition-77d6622a2a7c#:%7E:text=Using%20SwiftUI%20and%20image%20recognition,the%20objects%20in%20the%20image.) etc which is all focused on iOS, and not relevant to my use case.

Guidance with examples would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to this:

- Capturing the screen's contents
- Doing image recognition on the image
  you want to detect.

I haven't tried to capture the screen since Apple started sandboxing MacOS apps a LONG time ago, so I don't know what's involved in that, and don't have anything to offer.

Assuming you solve that problem, you need to tackle image recognition. Will the image always be the same size, oriented the same way? Will it be in an opaque box, or an irregular shape drawn on top of the other screen contents? Does it have holes in it as it appears to? The answers to those questions will have a big impact in how you scan for your target image.

I don't know if your image will be anti-aliased against the background. If so that will make recognizing it harder.

I'd suggest looking at OpenCV. If your image is fixed in size, doesn't get rotated, and isn't anti-aliased into the background it should be pretty easy to find it on screen in a performant way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The image will be static size, is not rotated, not anti aliased. It does have holes in it, which are transparent. I'll take a look at OpenCV!